# Help with filter in js for lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components

Filter in js- lwc

I'm trying to create a page in lwc. I've got my SOQL bringing what I need back but I need to then use filters to create 3 separate lists to be appropriately displayed.

I've tried both of these in my js. But I get the error

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')

or

> undefined (reading 'includes')

```js
const property\_rent = this.properties.filter(function(property) {  
    return property.Sale\_Type\_\_c == 'Rent';  
});        

const property\_rent = this.properties.find(prop => prop.Sale\_Type\_\_c.includes('Rent'));
```

Comment: are those backslashes really in your Javascript, or were you just trying to avoid things being interpreted as "markdown"?

Comment: Before you do anything else, remove those backslashes if they are in your code and try again.

Comment: No they're not in my code. I copied and pasted it and didn't realise it had auto edited to add them in